# The dynamic “edit tags” link causes everything below to slide downward

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags, design

When a user has enough rep points to edit the question, the hidden “edit tags” link on the question page appears only when a user hovers the mouse (at least on beta sites).  If a question has tags just enough to fill one line, the existence of this link causes everything below it to move downward, and this is awkward.  I am using Firefox 3.6.

Please use “visibility: hidden” in CSS instead of “display: none” to hide the link.

This issue is not new and I guess that this has been already reported, but I could not find a duplicate.

[image: Problem with “edit tags” link]

Comment: FYI, on non-beta sites, this is one of the 10k tools/privileges/thingsadongdong. Nice find though, +1.

Answer (score 1):

This is only true in the case of 5 exceptionally long tags, and even *then* only for users with 10k+ rep.

Otherwise, there's plenty of room for it.

Comment: This is a disappointing response.  Questions with five tags with about 20 characters each may be rare on Stack Overflow, but those “exceptionally long” tags are quite common on cstheory.stackexchange.com (and they have to be long because we cannot assume that many acronyms are understandable in the whole community of theoretical computer scientists).  Please reconsider the decision.

Comment: The proposed fix seems simple enough - is there a reason you're dismissing it out of hand?

Comment: @tsu see my edit. After your site leaves beta you'll need 10k rep plus 5 extra-long-tags for this to occur.

Comment: But you will have more and more beta sites if you are successful.  I hope that you consider those beta sites as something important.